# F# How to print out a sequence in a pipe forward sequence?

Tags: f#

Is it possible to print out a sequence in a pipe forward sequence? I have the following code:

```
  let rec crawlPage (page : String, nestingLevel : int) : seq<string> =    
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep 1200
        //printfn "URL: %s" page
        //printfn "Nesting Level: %i \n" nestingLevel
        HtmlDocument.Load(page)
        |> fun m -> m.CssSelect("a")
        |> List.map(fun a -> a.AttributeValue("href"))
        |> Seq.distinctBy id
        |> Seq.filter (fun x -> x.Contains baseUrl1)
        //|> Seq.map (printfn "%A") // I would like to be able to do something like this.
        |> Seq.map (fun x -> https + x) 
        |> Seq.map (fun x -> 
            match nestingLevel with
            | _ when (nestingLevel > 0) -> crawlPage(x, (nestingLevel - 1)) 
            | _ -> Seq.singleton x)
        |> Seq.concat
        |> Seq.distinctBy id
```

I was able to work around it by writing a helper function like follows:

```
let strPrint (str : string) : string =
    printfn "%s" str
    str
```

I would rather just use the pipe forwarding if possible though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, you can just do the exact same thing inline, with an anonymous function:

```
...
|> Seq.map (fun str ->
    printfn "%s" str
    str)
|>
...
```

As a rule, if you have `let f x = e`, you can always replace any occurrence of `f` with its anonymous equivalent `(fun x -> e)`